# Extrair apenas palavras em caixa alta com R

Tags: r, string

`library(stringr)`

Estou tentando extrair apenas as palavras em caixa alta de uma string.

```
teste <- "Isto é um Teste para ver se Eu consigo capturar APENAS as Palavras TOTALMENTE Maiusculas"
teste

[1] "Isto é um Teste para ver se Eu consigo capturar APENAS as Palavras TOTALMENTE Maiusculas"
```

Uso o `str_extract_all()` e passo uma REGEX que busca capturar apenas **palavras** "\w" que estejam grifadas como **uppercase** "[:upper:]"

A funçao até que localiza as palavras corretas, mas as divide a cada 2 letras.

```
str_extract_all(teste, "\\w[:upper:]")

[[1]]
[1] "AP" "EN" "AS" "TO" "TA" "LM" "EN" "TE"
```

Por que?

Qual a forma correta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode verificar se existem mais de uma ocorrência de letra maiúscula dentro do limite da palavra

```
str_extract_all(teste ,'\\b[A-Z]+\\b')
```

ou

```
str_extract_all(teste, "\\b[:upper:]+\\b")
```